# How to use easing inside a coroutine to change a float value?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, coroutine, easing, lerp

I would like to increase the value of a float over time but with added In-Out easing.

Here I'm using Mathf.Lerp and I know there is Mathf.Smoothstep but in SmoothStep, I can't seem to control the speed of the easing itself. I would like the easing to start from a certain value to another value over a specific time(range?) I choose. For example, if the float is changing from 0 to 100, I would like the easing to be from 0 to 20 and again from 70 to 100.

Here is the current code I'm using:

```
 float minValue = 0;
 float maxValue = 100;
 float duration = 10;
 
 float value;
 
 void Start()
 {
       StartCoroutine(IncreaseSpeed(minValue, maxValue, duration));
 }
  private IEnumerator IncreaseSpeed(float start, float end, float duration)
  {
     float time = 0;
     while (time <= duration)
     {
         time = time + Time.deltaTime;
         value = Mathf.Lerp(start, end, time / duration);
         yield return null;
     }
  }
```

Comment: You don’t need a coroutine because you are using the `time` class to manage the amount of time. You should just put this in an update function, and then you can adjust it he script to what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

```
{
    time  = time + Time.deltaTime;
    value = Mathf.Lerp(start, 20, time / duration);
    yield return new WaitUntil(()=> value == 20);
    value = Mathf.Lerp(20, 70, time / duration);
    yield return new WaitUntil(()=> value == 70);
    value = Mathf.Lerp(70, 100, time / duration);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.

I'm not sure what is going on but this code isn't running. I pasted it inside an IEnumerator and added a 'float time' at the top of the class but nothing is happening.